# How do I use Unity IoC in an MVC Validation Attribute?

Tags: c#, unity-container, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Unity Ioc injection working in Global Filters as well as Action and Controller filters. Now I need to get IoC working in Validation Attributes.

What is the best way to achieve this in MVC5?

Cheers Mike

Comment: Take a look at [this answer on CodePlex](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/472187#post1137461). It talks about extracting the logic from the attribute and place it inside a service. Although it's about Web API and Simple Injector, i think you'll find it useful, since the solution for Unity would be almost the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have adapted the suggested above for the Unity DI container.

Here is the new Model Validator

```
public class UnityModelValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer unityContainer;

    public UnityModelValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, 
        ControllerContext context, 
        ValidationAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        this.unityContainer = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnityContainer>();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
    {
        try
        {
            unityContainer.BuildUp(Attribute.GetType(), Attribute);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException ex)
        {
            //Don't understand why it sometimes tries to use Unity to create an attribute rather than just build up an existing object. If this happens it can fail but we want to ignore it.
        }

        ValidationContext context = CreateValidationContext(container);
        ValidationResult result = Attribute.GetValidationResult(Metadata.Model, context);
        if (result != ValidationResult.Success)
        {
            yield return new ModelValidationResult
            {
                Message = result.ErrorMessage
            };
        }
    }

    protected virtual ValidationContext CreateValidationContext(object container)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(container ?? Metadata.Model, new UnityServiceLocator(unityContainer), null);
        context.DisplayName = Metadata.GetDisplayName();
        return context;
    }
}
```

As well as performing the Buildup on the attribute it also adds the container as a ServiceProvider to the context so it can be used directly in the attribute. I know this is an anti-pattern and I do not want to use it myself, but it is included here for completeness sake.

Here is the unity config code

```
    container.RegisterType<ModelValidator, UnityModelValidator>(new TransientLifetimeManager());

    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterDefaultAdapterFactory(
        (metadata, context, attribute) => container.Resolve<ModelValidator>(new ParameterOverrides() { { "metadata", metadata }, { "context", context }, { "attribute", attribute } }));
```

Finally this means that we can build our validation attributes like this

```
public class InitialsMustBeAvailableAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public IUserService UserService { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return UserService.AreInitialsAvailable((string)value);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var userService = (IUserService)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IUserService));

        if (userService != null)
        {
            if (userService.AreInitialsAvailable((string) value))
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return new ValidationResult("Initals must be unique!");
    }
}
```

Please note that you would only actually use one of these methods. The first uses the UserService that has been injected, the second uses the ServiceLocator in the context to grab it itself.

I much prefer the former.

Cheers Mike

Comment: I have changed the code slightly. In certain circumstances it was failing when it was trying to build up an attribute from the framework. It would fail with the error, 'multiple constructors with 1 parameter found, cannot disambiguate'. No idea why it needed to access the constructor to perform a buildup, but we can safely ignore that error.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good way to inject dependencies to validation attributes. But there are two workarounds (http://forloop.co.uk/blog/resolving-ioc-container-services-for-validation-attributes-in-asp.net-mvc):

1. Create own ModelValidator that inherit from DataAnnotationModelValidator and inject dependencies. This solution is more elegant but your attributes will work only in MVC.
2. Use service-locator inside validation attribute - less elegant but it will be work globaly. You will be able to execute [`Validator.ValidateObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411788(v=vs.110).aspx) in any place

Comment: Not disagreeing with your suggestions, however some consider the `service locator` to be an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: @Veleous - I know that, but in some cases (like this) there is no better way. I think that there is nothing wrong with using anti-pattern if you do that intentionally.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of the custom ModelValidator that uses the Unity container and not the Castle Windsor container?